# Jolt exclude top level property

Tags: json, jolt

I have JSON:

```json
{
  "row0" : {
    "ID" : 136501,
    "impressionsAll" : 15002401,
    "clicksAll" : 312718
  },
  "row1" : {
    "ID" : 388288,
    "impressionsAll" : 28007952,
    "clicksAll" : 334596
  }
}
```

How can I exclude `row0` and `row1` from top level? Names can be different, but always start with `row...`. And can I transform it to array? Desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "ID" : 136501,
    "impressionsAll" : 15002401,
    "clicksAll" : 312718
  },
  {
    "ID" : 388288,
    "impressionsAll" : 28007952,
    "clicksAll" : 334596
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use such a shift transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

[image]